# SteamAPI JSON.net Error in VB .net

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, variables, json.net

I dont really understand what I do wrong when I try to Deserialize the JSON stuff I get.

You can get the response from http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?format=json

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim SteamGameInfoObject As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?format=json"))



    End Sub

    Public Class SteamRootObject

        Public Class SteamAPIJSONResult

            Public Property applist As List(Of applistlist)

        End Class

        Public Class applistlist

            Public Property apps As List(Of appslist)

        End Class

        Public Class appslist

            Public Property appid As Integer()
            Public Property name As String()

        End Class

    End Class

End Class
```

I dont know how to "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array"

Comment: You didnt tell us the first part of the error message, and we cant tell you how to fix that without seeing the code you are using.  It sounds like you are not deserialzing to an array type

Comment: I gonna edit it to the full source.

Comment: You constructed classes to hold the deserialized data, then didnt use them.  You should also allow that connecting and getting the json might fail by doing that as a separate step

Comment: It uses the constructed class now but I still get a error: "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type"

Comment: Those classes should not be nested, `SteamRootObject` is wrong, it should just be `Public Property applist as applistlist` since the dreadfully named `applistlist` is already a list.  The code shown **is not** using those classes.  `As Object` is not telling the deserializer to use those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You define `appid` and `name` as arrays of integers and strings, respectively.  In the JSON these are primitive values not arrays, so the VB.NET properties themselves should be declared to be simple integers and strings.
2. You define `applist` as a `List(Of applistlist)`.  Despite the name, the property value in the JSON is a single object not an array, so the property should refer to a single object also.
3. In `Form1_Load` you need to deserialize to the correct type, `SteamRootObject`.  If you do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(jsonString)` you are not telling Json.NET the type to which to deserialize!
4. Stylistically there is no need to nest the inner classes inside the root class, it adds to complexity.

There are plenty of on-line tools to auto-generate .Net classes from JSON that can be found quickly using [google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=generate+vb.net+classes+from+json&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t), for instance http://json2csharp.com/ (for c#) or http://jsonutils.com/ or http://www.httputility.net/json-to-csharp-vb-typescript-class.aspx.  In the future, use one of these to check your work.

Thus your fixed classes should look like:

```
Public Class App
    Public Property appid As Integer
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class Applist
    Public Property apps As New List(of App)
End Class

Public Class SteamRootObject
    Public Property applist As Applist
End Class
```

And, to deserialize:

```
Dim SteamGameInfoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of SteamRootObject)(jsonString)
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QZw7P).

Comment: Thanks for the help.